# Color SVG to Font

Tags: ios, svg, fonts, colors, icon-fonts

I have a color SVG I'd like to use in a font on iOS. It's basically a green circle with a white star on top.

It seems like this should be possible (emojis have multiple colors), but the tools I've seen online for making fonts from SVGs don't *seem* to support this -- I can only produce solid color fonts. (eg https://icomoon.io/app and https://glyphter.com )

For now, an acceptable solution is to use a non-colored circle with a transparent star cut out of it, and then set the color of the font to green. This works, because for now we are only using it on a white background, but it would be nice to have a solution where the font stores the exact icon we want.

Comment: This may be a question for something like http://www.typedrawers.com, rather than stackoverflow, since you're essentially asking people for tool recommendations, not programming help. There are lots of font editors out there, some free, many for pay. You want a font editor that supports, specificaly, either the color tables (see https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm#otttables, "Tables Related to Color Fonts") or straight up SVG-for-your-outlines ("Table related to SVG outlines").

Comment: Is the problem that I simply need the right tool, or that I'm misunderstanding something about fonts?

Comment: You just need the right tool. The typedrawers folks, as specifically a typography community, will be able to much better help you find that tool.